# Is there a "use explicit type refactoring" in VSCode/TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

Is there a way I can copy to clipboard the full path of an inferred type?

Example:

```
class App { listen(){ const server = expressApp.listen()}}
```

I want to make `server` a member and not a local, but I don't know the type. Is there 1 click to get type?

I think C# has this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/convert-var-to-explicit-type?view=vs-2019

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT:**

To get the types of a function return you can use the `ReturnType` type constructor. Combine that with type indexing using bracket notation and you can find the return type of an interface member like so:

```
type Server = ReturnType<Express['listen']>;
```

---

The Node standard module `http` exposes a type called `Server`. Since Express uses this type for its server listeners, you can use it to type the listener on your member like so:

```
import type { Express } from "express";
import type { Server } from "http";

class App {
  constructor(app: Express) {
    this.listener = app.listen();
  }
  private listener: Server;
}
```

If you want to use a custom `listen()` function with an uninitialized `server` variable as you're doing in your above code snippet, you just need to make the property optional:

```
class App {
  private server?: Server;
  listen(expressApp: Express) {
    this.server = expressApp.listen()
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! You are absolutely correct that this solves the specific case. But I often run into this general problem, and so am looking for a faster method to solve this than my current method (which is "Go to Type Definition", and then manually figure out an import strategy to that definition). TypeScript clearly has the import path figured out, so I'd love it if it would share with me ;)

Comment: Ah I see, yeah that would be nice  I never even considered that there was an easier way to do it. Updating my answer (it's not pretty but it works)